# When did the Ecclesiastical courts in England lose the authority to mete out punishments such as imprisonment and execution?

Tags: religion, law, england

In 1401, the ecclesiastical courts in England were given the power to burn heretics. In modern times the ecclesiastical courts have no control over anyone who does not belong to the Church of England, and can't give out 'serious' punishments like imprisonment.

When were they stripped of powers like this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand the question. Especially on matters of jurisdiction, it is better to absolutely clear on the question.

Comment: I'm off to bed, but I'd lay odds that it was during the c 1180 judicial rewrite by Henry II - Yeah, that guy who did penance for the murder of Beckett.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the *[Suppression of Heresy Act 1400](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780198614425.001.0001/acref-9780198614425-e-1622)* (enacted 1401) - *[De Hæretico Comburendo](http://www.ric.edu/faculty/rpotter/heretico.html)* - didn't grant the ecclesiastical courts in England the power to burn heretics. Anyone convicted of heresy was to be handed over to the secular power

> *... the sheriff of the county of the same place, and mayor and sheriffs, or sheriff, or mayor and bailiffs of the city, town, and
>   borough of the same county ...*

who would then carry out the sentence as laid down by the law.

---

The 1401 statute was repealed by the [1558 Act of Supremacy](https://history.hanover.edu/texts/engref/er79.html) under Elizabeth I.

---

There is an article titled [A Brief History of Medieval Roman Canon Law in England](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3694215.pdf?refreqid=excelsior:4671d3894179ae4b5877f49650ad5c9a) which you might also find interesting available on JSTOR.

Comment: Good catch - didn't know what OP was asking. This book could be useful too - [**The Detection of Heresy in Late Medieval England**](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199286928.001.0001/acprof-9780199286928), (2005). Good review [**here**](http://www.history.ac.uk/reviews/review/587).